# How can you check if a specific integer occurs in a double?

Tags: java, double

Here are the specifics.

Say I have an integer 3.

How can I determine if 3 occurs in the any of the decimal places of a double. Say 0.098734. I understand you can cast the double as a String and then search the string, but is there a way to do it with modulus or some other means?

Comment: Doubles are made of 0 and 1's. There are no 3's. Therefore the bits don't match the decimals (if you were interested in the hexadecimal scientific notation, things may be different).

Comment: Doubles don't contain "decimal places". Note that 0.098734 cannot be exactly represented as a double; and that (for example) the values 1.0000000000000000000000000002, 1.0000000000000000000000000003, and 1.0000000000000000000000000004 are all approximated by the same double. You need to formalize your requirement.

Comment: if you need some exact double, take a look at [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). You can store up to `10^(-(2^31-1))` precision digits in there. Given you know how many precision digits you stored in there, you can always calc `(d*10^p)%10` to get the digit of the number `d` at precision `p`

Comment: I'm interested in the first 2 comments on this question.  Is there some reading to back up your claims?  I'd like to learn more about this.  @ruakh and @ n.caillou?

Comment: @XaolingBao: If you Google "double precision", you will find all the reading you could possibly want.

Answer (score 0):

A double has is not exact and the difference to the next double varies.
So consider that a double has at most a [precision of ca 17 digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), then:

```
boolean hasDecimalDigit(double x, int digit) {
    if (x < 0) {
        x = -x;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; ++i) {
        x *= 10;
        if (((int)x) % 10) == digit) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

This may very well be not in concordance with the String representation,
which often is a bit beautified.

Also there are limitations, overflow. Taking first modulo 1 may diminish some effects, but even taken modulo already may introduce garbage precision for huge numbers.

For maintaining a precision use BigDecimal as in:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("0.098734");
```

This gives an exact fixed-point math with precision.

Answer (score -1):

Convert to a string (like you'd do when printing it out) and then do a charAt or indexOf comparison